# Passar variável para outro arquivo php

Tags: php, variáveis

Estou fazendo um sistema onde o usuario faz o upload de um vídeo e automaticamente já é criada uma pagina no site com o vídeo. Consegui fazer o upload e a criação da pagina, porem eu uso um iframe para colocar o vídeo na pagina(que é gerada) e para passar o src do iframe eu uso o seguinte src="pasta/$novo_nome" a variável novo nome é gerada pelo arquivo de upload, mas não consigo fazer com que o usuário faça o upload e depois essa variável seja passado para dentro do arquivo de geração de pagina.

Por algum motivo não to conseguindo colocar o código aqui, então botei no pastebin.

Upload: https://pastebin.com/LhM4Uy2T
Gerador de paginas: https://pastebin.com/Rvu8KNWv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é simples, basta você implementar:

Após o upload do arquivo você pode redirecionar o usuário para a página do vídeo e para o arquivo que tem o iframe saber qual vídeo está sendo "pedido" você usa `Query String`:

```
<?php
    include("conexao.php");

    $msg = false;

    if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){

        $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4));
        $novo_nome = md5(time()) .$extensao;
        $diretorio = "animes/";


        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);

        $sql_code = "INSERT INTO arquivo (codigo, arquivo, data) VALUES (null, '$novo_nome', NOW())";
        if ($mysqli->query($sql_code))
            $msg = "Arquivo enviado. <a href='gerador_paginas.php?video=".$novo_nome."'>Clique aqui</a> para gerar o HTML";

        else 
            $msg = "Falha ao enviar.";

    }
?>
```

Após isso, você recupera da URL qual o nome do arquivo a ser exibido:

```
<?php
$novo_nome = $_GET['video'];

$arquivo = fopen($novo_nome, "w");
$texto = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head>
    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src=\"upload/animes/$novo_nome\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>
</body>
</html>";
fwrite($arquivo, $texto);
?>
```

E também você pode criar como se fosse uma playlist, listando os vídeos e sempre redirecionando pra **sua_pagina.php?video=NOME_DO_VIDEO**

Uma dica que recomendo é nunca usar **nomes** em `Query String` pois pode ser um problema lá na frente pra você. Seria legal usar a ID do registro inserido no banco referente aquele vídeo, depois você pega a ID via Query String e faz a consulta no MySQL para retornar o nome do vídeo.

Eu não entendi a necessidade somente de criar um arquivo html contendo o iframe, pois se tiver muitos vídeos, criará muitos arquivos em seu servidor. Caso você queira só deixar o usuário fazer o upload do vídeo e depois deixar esse vídeo acessível, apenas crie uma página que pegue a query string e monte o HTML sem precisar salvar um arquivo novo em seu servidor, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
$novo_nome = $_GET['video'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="upload/animes/<?php echo $novo_nome;?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom eu crio varias paginas para depois poder ser acessível para qualquer usuário, seria tipo um site de stream

Comment: Uma só sendo dinamica não supriria sua necessidade? Veja esse último código que postei, ele faz ser dinamico. Imagina que você tenha 1.000 arquivos gerados e você precisa alterar o layout, isso seria uma dor de cabeça para você.

Comment: Mas tipo teria como fazer essa pagina que voce colocou uma para cada video? Tipo na index ter um link para cada video postado no site.

Comment: Teria um link pra cada vídeo, mas nesses links o que iria alterar será somente o conteúdo da query string, no caso ?video=**NOME_ARQUIVO** ... Nesse NOME_ARQUIVO você fará dinamico, puxando os itens cadastrado no banco de dados e colocar o nome no lugar

Comment: Vou tentar isso, vlw pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Toniotti

Após o upload como chama o arquivo de criação da pagina?
Pode passar a variável para o arquivo de criação por post ou get dependendo como está chamando a pagina de criação.

Outra solução seria realizar um select na tabela onde inseriu o nome do video uma vez que realiza um insert no banco com o valor da variável.

Answer (score 0):

Se gradar a uma superglobal $_SESSION[] , diferente dos cookies ,ela fica guardada no servidor e voce pode compartilhar entre as paginas.